# boxSize leaking to globalscope

Tags: javascript, global-scope

Console log two times but it needs to show only the first console.log(boxSize)

```
var size = 100;
if (size > 50) {
    var boxSize = size * 5;
    console.log(boxSize);
}
console.log(boxSize);
```

Comment: You should delete one of console.log(boxSize)

Comment: It works as it should, use `let` instead of `var` when declaring `boxSize`. Check "Block Scoping Rules" here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a behaviour called **hoisting** in Javascript.

> Hoisting is a JavaScript mechanism where variables and function
>   declarations are moved to the top of their scope before code
>   execution.

`var` in javascript are not block scoped.
You can use the keywords `let` or `const` in ES6 which declare variables which are only available to the block where it s declared.

```
var size = 100;
if (size > 50) {
    let boxSize = size * 5;
    console.log(boxSize);
}
console.log(boxSize);// Uncaught ReferenceError: boxSize is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using let over var for this

> The difference is scoping. var is scoped to the nearest function block and let is scoped to the nearest enclosing block, which can be smaller than a function block. Both are global if outside any block.

src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11444416/4891666

**Example:**

```js
var size = 100;

/* Using Var */
if (size > 50) {
  var varExample = size * 5;
  console.log("With var inner: " + varExample);
}
console.log("With var outer: " + varExample);

/* Using Let */
if (size > 50) {
  let letExample = size * 5;
  console.log("With let inner: " + letExample);
}
console.log("With let outer: " + letExample);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let size = 100;
if (size > 50) {
  let boxSize = size * 5;
    console.log(boxSize);
}
console.log(boxSize);
/* Es6 let declers a block scope
  local variable(not function level scope like var)
  */
  //trying to access the variable in the block before the variable declaration resulsts in a ReferenceError
```